# How can I start displaying my setup in Netlogo after a certain number of ticks?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I have a simulation which I like to start displaying after 20 ticks, while the program run in the previous ticks but without display.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, you just have to use [the `no-display` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#no-display) and set your model view updates to be `on ticks` instead of `continuous`.

Below is a sample that will have some turtles move forward in the 20 ticks, then spin in place once their actions become visible.  Setup a normal `setup` button and `go` forever button, then when you hit `go` you will not see the turtles move `forward`.  Once they're moved, I use [the `display` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#display) to have the rest of the actions show as normal.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ifelse ticks < 20 [
    no-display
    ask turtles [ fd 0.2 ]
  ] [
    display
  ]
  ask turtles [ lt (10 - random 20) ]
  tick
end
```

A side note is that this technique will not work in NetLogo Web, since the `display` and `no-display` primitives do not work there yet.  An alternative if you need to run in NLW in this way is to use `repeat` instead.  This is *not* how I'd recommend building a model in general, but in this case it gets the job done:

```
to go-repeat
  ifelse ticks = 0 [
    no-display
    repeat 20 [
      ask turtles [ fd 0.2 ]
      tick
    ]
  ] [
    display
    ask turtles [ lt (10 - random 20) ]
    tick
  ]
end
```